# `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment

Tags: mysql

Some scripts I migrated are doing lots of

```
INSERT INTO `table` ( `id` , `fld2` , `fld3`) VALUES ( '', 'v2', 'v3')
```

`id` is defined as: `int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment`.

My database/mysql server (5.1.57) throws error:

```
1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

`''` was being accepted without syntax error and did auto-increment the integer field to the next number on the original server (5.1.52).  Any idea what could be the difference in the mysql server setup?  It couldn't be the version difference, both are 5.1.xx?

Comment: What happens when you run INSERT INTO table ( fld2 , fld3) VALUES ( 'v2', 'v3') ?

Answer (score 4):

Since id is auto_increment you should not mention it in your insert query :

```
INSERT INTO table (fld2 , fld3) VALUES ('v2', 'v3')
```

And besides you are inserting string in your id thus in case it was not auto_increment you would get the same error anyway.

Comment: if you absolutely have to provide a value for that column then include it but instead of setting it as `''` pass in `NULL` and it'll be auto incremented too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the current server's default settings differ from the previous one. Have a look at MySQL's documentation regarding the [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) settings.

Comment: This seems to be the culprit. But after removing sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION", restart server, create new database, SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode still shows "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: SET @@global.sql_mode= '';  Problem Solved.